# Can translation of user interface and list names be disabled in a multilingual Sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, search, graphical-user-interface, language

I'm in the process of configuring Microsoft Office Server Search for a Sharepoint web site. The web site needs multilingual support, so for indexing and search queries to work properly we need to install the language packs for each supported language.

The problem we are facing is that we do not want all the features brought on by the language packs, namely the translation of the user interface and lists etc. Actually, the only reason we want the language packs installed would be for search to fully support each language.

So what I'm asking is if it's possible to set up each site (or subsite) with the correct language setting, but disable the translation of user editing interfaces, lists etc?

Regards,
Magnus

Answer (score 1):

The Page Layout and Site Template Settings page (`_layouts/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx`) has a dropdown that allows you to select the language of the allowed site templates. If you allow site creation using only the site templates in your primary language, then the UI and list metadata will stay in that language.